# Azure DevOps VNet integration

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-virtual-network, azure-vpn

We have an on-premises data centre that is connected to Azure via VPN.
There are some on-premises Jenkins jobs that need to run when code is pushed in the Azure repository, and there is an on-premises Nexus server to store artifacts from other Azure pipelines. The rest can and should run in Azure.

I know there is a possibility to use a self-hosted agent that is placed in the Azure virtual network which could then connect to on-premises, but we do not want to manage/pay for a self-hosted agent.
My question is, is there something like a virtual network integration for Azure DevOps? The idea is to let DevOps connect to on-premises resources via the Azure VNet and the VPN without self-hosted agents in between.
E.g., does the ARM Service Connection only allow to access resources like VMs for deployments or does it also allow to connect to a VNet and the via VPN connected resources on-premises?

Thanks in advance!

I have already created a service connection between DevOps and the Azure subscription. I cannot check whether the connection to on-premises works for internal reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Microsoft hosted agents for Azure DevOps only allow for public internet connections to other resources. VPN and Use of expressroute or other connections to the internal corporate network are not supported. See [this section of the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#networking) for reference.